# Quais as definições do view, serializer e model do Django?

Tags: django, view, model, django-rest-framework

Estou estudando o **'Django'** e gostaria de entender as definições view, serializer e model e qual a rota entre elas.

Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**View**

O View no Django é a camada de lógica de negócios. É responsável pelo processamento da solicitação do usuário e pelo envio de uma resposta válida. Ele busca os dados do *model*, fornece a cada *model* acesso a dados específicos para exibição ou pode executar algum processamento sobre os dados de antemão. Atualmente, as *views* do Django podem ser funções que processam a requisição e retornam uma resposta ou classes.

**Model**

O *model* do Django faz uso de uma camada ORM poderosa que simplifica o tratamento do banco de dados e dos dados e acelera o processo de desenvolvimento.

Sem o ORM(Object relational mapper), os desenvolvedores teriam que criar as próprias tabelas e definir as consultas ou procedimentos que às vezes se traduzem em uma grande quantidade de SQL que é propensa a ser complexa e difícil de rastrear.

A camada ORM permite que você escreva todas as definições da tabela em código Python simples, e cuida de traduzi-la para a linguagem de consulta apropriada escolhida, além de facilitar as operações CRUD.
Na verdade, o desenvolvedor não precisa necessariamente conhecer completamente o SQL complexo ou o que ele significa, no entanto, vale a pena observar que o SQL permitiria que você escrevesse consultas melhores e mais rápidas e também tornasse seu site mais seguro.

**Serializer**

Usando Serializers, podemos traduzir objetos do model do Django em outros formatos como XML, JSON, YAML (YAML não é uma linguagem de marcação) que podem ser usados nas suas views.

**Como que acontece o fluxo de uma requisição**

O fluxo de uma requisição segue o modelo MVT(Model, View e Template) do Django que uma variação do modelo MVC(Model, View e Controller)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]